# How to find how many numbers from an array don't include certain digits?

Tags: python, performance

I have an array of numbers, and I need a fast solution to remove all the elements that contain certain digits. So if we have an array with all the numbers from 20 to 49, and the digits we need to get rid of are 3, 5, 6 and 7, we would remain with: 20, 21, 22, 24, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```
new_l=[x for x in range(N) if not any(str(y) in str(x) for y in A)]
print(new_l,len(new_l))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is not a concern you could do something like this:

```
N = 23
A = [1, 6]

res = []
for i in range(N):
    for j in str(i):
        if int(j) in A:
            break
    else:
        res.append(i)

print(res)
print(len(res))
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22]
10
```

Comment: performance is actually my problem.. this was my solution too but it takes a lot of time to process